# how to display a scrollable treeview control on wpf form

Tags: wpf, treeview, scroll

how to render a scrollable wpf treeview control on a window that occupies the left corner of the window and adjusts with the height of the window. I have been experimenting with Grid and dockpanel but the scrollbar does not appear unless you specify the height. please answer with a XAML markup.

Answer (score 2):

Tell me if this is what you need:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Name="window" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TreeView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=TreeviewDummySource}" 
        Background="Gray" 
        Width="150" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Dummy ItemSource:

```
    public int[] TreeviewDummySource
    {
        get { return treeviewDummySource; }
    }

    private int[] treeviewDummySource = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
```

So the trick is that the ScrollBar will appear only if the content of the ScrollViewer is larger than the available size. By specifying the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` in TreeView properties the scrollviewer will always be present (enabled or disabled). Try changing the height of the window to see how the ScrolBar gets enabled.

Comment: how do I make so that the treeview control fills the height of the screen.

Comment: The example above makes the tree-view take all available vertical space - all window height. If you want the window to take all screen space, set the WindowState="Maximized" for window properties.